# MediaWiki recursiveTagParse returns false

Tags: extension-methods, mediawiki

I am writing an extension for internal use in my group.  It takes some parameters and should return a table of DRs for the release we are working on.  It queries our ClearQuest, and its all working great.  However, when more than 606 (a common occurrence) rows are in the table no output is returned at all.

I write the table using wiki markup ( {|...|} ) and send that through to recursiveTagParse.  I checked and recursiveTagParse is returning false.  is have tried to gig a little bit, but can't find the reason it would return false instead of output.

I am assuming recursiveTagParse won't process large inputs.  Does anyone know of some variable I can set to force recursiveTagParse to do it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

To fix my problem I just used regular html and did not run it through recursiveTagParse before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the sanest approach; parser extensions in MediaWiki are supposed to return HTML. It's fine to generate this yourself; in fact, if you don't need to, don't invoke the parser - it's a pretty expensive call, and requires some fancy footwork to not screw everything up in a recursive call.